# how to fix npm install sqlite3 error on mac?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm-install, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to install sqlite3 with npm on mac however the following error follows

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info build requesting source compile
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ryan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/ryan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/ryan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1502, in XcodeVersion
npm ERR!     version_list = GetStdoutQuiet(["xcodebuild", "-version"]).splitlines()
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1563, in GetStdoutQuiet
npm ERR!     raise GypError("Error %d running %s" % (job.returncode, cmdlist[0]))
npm ERR! gyp.common.GypError: Error 1 running xcodebuild
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 45, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 662, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 654, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 639, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2455, in GenerateOutput
npm ERR!     writer.Write(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 798, in Write
npm ERR!     self.WriteActions(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 932, in WriteActions
npm ERR!     env = self.GetSortedXcodeEnv()
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2108, in GetSortedXcodeEnv
npm ERR!     return gyp.xcode_emulation.GetSortedXcodeEnv(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1888, in GetSortedXcodeEnv
npm ERR!     env = _GetXcodeEnv(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1743, in _GetXcodeEnv
npm ERR!     "XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL": XcodeVersion()[0],
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1513, in XcodeVersion
npm ERR!     version = CLTVersion()  # macOS Catalina returns 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1551, in CLTVersion
npm ERR!     return re.search(regex, output).groupdict()["version"]
npm ERR! AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/ryana/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ryan/Desktop/12SDE/Formative-1/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ryan/.npm/_logs/2021-12-02T07_55_52_766Z-debug.log
```

I am not really sure what to do as it pushes me to download an xcode developers thing. Must i download it or is there a solution to resolve this error.

- node version v16.13.1
- npm version 8.1.2
- command used `npm install sqlite3`
- sqlite3 version 3.32.3

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment and the npm command you are using to install sqlit3?

Comment: the node version i am using is v16.13.1

Comment: the npm version i am using is 8.1.2

Comment: the command i used was - npm install sqlite3

Comment: the sqlite3 version i have installed is 3.32.3

Comment: I do get similar errors if I try to install any v3.x.x
But I'm able to install sqlite3 in the version 4.2.0 and 5.0.2.
So this seems to be related to the version you are trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

In npm there seems to be no version 3.32.3.
The npm versioning is not the same as the version of the sqlite3.

But I get similar errors if I try to install any 3.x.x version via npm.

But I was also able to install sqlite3@4.2.0 aswell as sqlite@5.0.2 via npm.

[Here you can find the version history for the sqlite3 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3?activeTab=versions)

Edit:
The current version of the npm sqlite3 package (Time of writing 5.0.2) will [ship sqlite 3.32.3 internaly](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#features) if you do not have sqlite3 installed on your system!

Maybe you have to clean your npm cache or uninstall you local sqlite3 version in order to be able to install the sqlite3 package from npm?

Comment: how do you find out the version of the npm sqlite as the version im talking about is the one intalled on my laptop

Comment: Check for global installed versions with `npm list -g --depth 0 | grep sqlite`.

Check for project specific versions with `npm list --depth 0 | grep sqlite`. If you have a global version installed, uninstall it. Other than that I can only guess that the local installed sqlite3 on your machine is interferring with the sqlite3 version that is shipped with the npm package.